# Как получить текущую цену активы используя ibapi Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно получить текущую цену актива, как я понял есть цена last и trade, мне нужна trade, я почитал [документацию](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/md_receive.html#market_data_return) и нашел только как получать last цену. У меня аккаунт с платной подпиской на interactivebrokers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и непонятно какую именно цену вы хотите получить, потому как есть две текущих цены `ask` и `bid`
Вот список доступных значений [Available Tick Types](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html)

Вам похоже нужно одно из этих значений:

```
Tick Name        Tick Id    Description Delivery                        Method

Last RTH Trade     57       Last Regular Trading Hours traded price.    IBApi.EWrapper.tickPrice
Mark Price         37       theoretical calculated value.               EWrapper.tickPrice
```